# loop through different arguments in Rscript within Korn shell

Tags: r, terminal, ksh

I have an R script which I'm running in the terminal by firstly generating a .ksh file called myscript.ksh with the following information:

```
#!/bin/ksh

Rscript myscript.R 'Input1'
```

and then run the function with

```
./mycode.ksh
```

which sends the script to a node on the cluster in our department (the processes that we send to the cluster must be as a .ksh file).

'Input1' is an input argument that is used by the R script to some analysis.

The issue that I now have is that I need to run this script a number of times with different input arguments to the function. One solution is to generate a few .ksh files, such as:

```
#!/bin/ksh

Rscript myscript.R 'Input2'
```

and

```
#!/bin/ksh

Rscript myscript.R 'Input3'
```

and then execute them seperately, but I was hoping to find a better solution.

Note that I have to do this for 100 different input arguments so it is not realistic to write 100 of these files. Is there a way of generating another file with the information needed to be supplied to the function e.g. 'Input1' 'Input2' 'Input3' and then run myscript.ksh for these individually.

For example, I could have a variable defining the name of the input arguments and then have a loop which would pass it to myscript.ksh. Is that possible?

The reason for running these in this manner is so that each iteration will hopefully be send to a different node on the cluster, thus analysing the data at a much faster rate.

Comment: Are the input parameters all named consistently -- i.e., Input#, where # is from 1 ... 100?

Comment: No. They have specific names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Create an array of all your input variables
2. Loop through the array and initiate all your calls

The following illustrates the concept:

```
#!/bin/ksh

#Create array of inputs - space separator 
inputs=(Input1 Input2 Input3 Input4)

# Loop through all the array items {0 ... n-1}
for i in {0..3}
do
   echo ${inputs[i]}
done
```

This will output all the values in the inputs array.

You just need to replace the contents of the do-loop with:

```
Rscript myscript.R ${inputs[i]}
```

Also, you may need to add a ` &' at the end of the Rscript command line to spawn off each Rscript command as a separate thread -- otherwise, the shell would wait for a return from each Rscript command before going onto the next.

---

EDIT:

Based on your comments, you need to actually generate .ksh scripts to submit to `qsub`.  For this you just need to expand the `do` loop.

For example:

#!/bin/ksh

```
#Create array of inputs - space separator 
inputs=(Input1 Input2 Input3 Input4)

# Loop through all the array items {0 ... n-1}
for i in {0..3}
do
   cat > submission.ksh << EOF
       #!/bin/ksh

       Rscript myscript.R ${inputs[i]}
EOF

   chmod u+x submission.ksh

   qsub submission.ksh
done
```

The `EOF` defines the beginning and end of what will be taken as input (STDIN) and the output (STDOUT) will written to submission.ksh.

Then submission.ksh is made executable with the `chmod` command.

And then the script is submitted via `qsub`.  I'll let you fill in any other arguments you need for `qsub`.

Comment: The issue with this is that I need to execute a different .ksh script for each input argument (in order for it to be sent to a different node on the cluster). What you have suggested would send the .ksh to one cluster. Say that I wanted to do this for 2 different runs one with input 'input1' and the other with an input argument of 'blahblah'. I think I need another file to generate the different .ksh scripts (each ksh overwriting the last) and to execute with qsub myscript.ksh

Comment: Edited answer to respond to your clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

When your script doesn't know all parameters when it starts, you can make a .ksh file called mycode.ksh with the following information:

```
#!/bin/ksh

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
   echo "Usage: $0 input"
   exit 1
fi
# Or start at the background with nohup .... &, other question
Rscript myscript.R "$1"
```

and then run the function with
    ./mycode.ksh inputX

When your application knows all arguments, you can use a loop:

```
#!/bin/ksh
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Usage: $0 input(s)"
   exit 1
fi
for input in $*; do
   Rscript myscript.R "${input}"
done
```

and then run the function with

```
./mycode.ksh input1 input2 "input with space in double quotes" input4
```